# is a ++ before a container the same as moving the index by one?

Tags: c++

I am unfamiliar with this syntax: `++fCount[index]`.  Where `list` is another vector.

I was thinking it was the same as below, but its not:

```
int i = 0;
vector<int> fCount(1001,0);
for(auto index : list)
{
    fCount[i] = index;
    i++;
}
```

piece of code:

```
vector<int> fCount(1001,0);
for(auto index : list)
{
    ++fCount[index];
}
```

Comment: `++fCount[index]` is parsed as `++( fCount[index] )`, not `( ++fCount )[index]`.  Your `++` is before a `int &`.

Comment: Note the existence of [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) returns a *reference* to an element at a given index.

The [`++` increment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) increments the value of a variable.

The two codes examples you have shown are NOT equivalent.

The first code is looping through `list`, assigning each of its elements as-is to sequential elements of `fCount`.  A `range-for` loop does not provide access to the indexes of the elements being iterated through, so a separate `i` variable is being used to index into `fCount`, where `i` is initialized to index 0, and `i++` increments the value of `i` by `1` on each loop iteration.  For example:

```
vector<int> list = {5, 10, 15, 20, ...};

int i = 0;
vector<int> fCount(1001,0);
for(auto index : list)
{
    fCount[i] = index;
    i++;
}
```

This is effectively filling `fCount` like this:

```
vector<int> fCount(1001,0);
fCount[0] = 5;
fCount[1] = 10;
fCount[2] = 15;
fCount[3] = 20;
...
```

The second code is using each element of `list` as an index into `fCount`, using the `++` operator to increment the value of each indexed element of `fCount`.  This is because `++fCount[index]` is using the **prefix** increment operator, which has a [lower precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `vector::operator[]`, so `++fCount[index]` is parsed as `++(fCount[index])`, not as `(++fCount)[index]` (IOW, `fCount` is indexed into first, and then the increment is applied to what `operator[]` returns). And since `fCount` is initialized with `0`s before the loop, after the loop finishes then every element that was indexed will have a value of exactly `1`.  For example:

```
vector<int> list = {5, 10, 15, 20, ...};

vector<int> fCount(1001,0);
for(auto index : list)
{
    ++fCount[index];
}
```

This is effectively filling `fCount` like this:

```
vector<int> fCount(1001,0);
fCount[5] += 1;
fCount[10] += 1;
fCount[15] += 1;
fCount[20] += 1;
...
```